# Word to describe when, where or how privacy is kept, trust is maintained, and integrity matters

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, synonyms, metaphors, psychology

Here is a list of scenarios on [why honest people would need privacy and anonymity](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/95751/396).

My marketing research tells me that the word "anonymity" is too closely related to hacking, and "privacy" reminds people of stealthy operations or unsavory deeds.

I think that privacy is needed for testing the expression of ideas, or maturing them with feedback... not to mention all the other scenarios listed on that page.

What is a good word or phrase to describe privacy in a honest or positive light?  I want to avoid any negative connotation implied with most synonyms provided.

The word can be a noun, adjective, or phrase.  I'm just trying to escape the negative connotations of privacy and enter into some other branch of thinking

**Use Case**

I'm [developing a product](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/76114/2139) that combines the seemingly conflicting use cases of anonymity and accountability, and putting them into practice as an iOS or Android app.  I need to name the app, create relevant marketing material and education, and to convey the sense of trust and safety that I'm envisioning.

There is a difference in implied meaning with the words `anonymity`, `trust` and `privacy` within "IT Security / Techies / Nerds" circles, vs what is seen by conspiracy theorists (not target audience), vs average joe.

The latter is my target audience.  I'm a nerd.

Comment: "discreet"/"discretion"?

Comment: made minor edits... I think "Haven" would be a suitable metaphor with positive connotation.

Comment: Isn't what you listed in your question exactly what *security* is supposed to convey? Also, *privacy* is the word used for real world situations (such as defining how far paparazzi are allowed to go when going after public figures).

Comment: Frankly, I don't see the problem with defending a person's "right to privacy". The word doesn't have any negative connotations to me. But "personal" also works. A person has a right to a personal life, personal effects, personal confidence. Speaking of which "confidential" also works, but it, too, has additional baggage.

Comment: I think the use case for this word needs clarification.

Comment: @user662852 why not add it as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I'm reaching here. But it looks like you safeguard confidentiality to nurture freedom of expression?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use "individual review".

As in: Those files are private --> those files are under individual review.

Comment: This may be an appropriate phrase to use in certain circumstances, but it isn't a very general word. Can you explain in what circumstances it would normally be used?

Comment: @curiousdannii you're right - I just tried to include all the connotations of privacy, but make it sound neutral.  I have personally never used the term!

Answer (score 0):

If you reject *privacy*, **Private life** is a possibility. Coupled with **preservation**, it may bring the expected positiveness.